# TextArea Not Work JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

hello i want to get text from textarea but with javascript not work where is problem any idea?

on alter show me: `undefined` ?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

        var get_text = $("#post_text").value;

        $(".new_post").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax/ajax_new_post.php",
            data: get_text,
            success: function() {
                alert(get_text);
                $('#post_text').val('');
            }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
    </script>
<div class="column_2 float_left">
    <div class="boxstatus" style="border: 1px solid #D3D6DB;">
        <textarea id="post_text" placeholder="What's on your mind?"></textarea>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is `new_post` ??

Comment: add the code then :)

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery, the syntax is `val()`

```
var get_text = $("#post_text").val();
```

to get the value...
To set value, you need to pass parameter to same method

```
$("#post_text").val("Text to set in text area");
```

Hope it helps

**EDIT**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(".new_post").click(function(){
            var get_text = $("#post_text").val();
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax/ajax_new_post.php",
            data: get_text,
            success: function() {
                alert(get_text);
                $('#post_text').val('');
            }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
    </script>
    <div class="column_2 float_left">
    <div class="boxstatus" style="border: 1px solid #D3D6DB;">
    <textarea id="post_text" placeholder="What's on your mind?"></textarea>
    <button class="float_right new_post" style="cursor: pointer;">Post</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: i want only to get no to set.

Comment: Ok sorry, you need to put it inside the click event